# How to add custom properties to a custom webcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls

I want to add custom typed properties to a webcontrol, like for example EditRowStyle in GridView, but in a way that the property's properties can be declared in Source view in ascx/aspx. It's clear that GridView hasn't got a property like EditRowStyle-BackColor, but only EditRowStyle has. Something like this:

```
public class MyCustomGrid : GridView
{
  [...]
  private MyCustomSettings customSettings;
  public MyCustomSettings CustomSettings
        {
            get { return customSettings; }
        }
  [...]
}

public class MyCustomSettings 
{
  private string cssClass = "default";
  public string CssClass
  {
    get { return cssClass; }
    set { cssClass = value; }
  }
}
```

And the grid decalartion:

```
<c1:MyCustomGrid ID="grdCustom" runat="server" CustomSettings-CssClass="customcss" />
```

Because this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyCustomGrid : GridView
{
  [...]
  private MyCustomSettings customSettings;
  [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
  public MyCustomSettings CustomSettings
        {
            get { return customSettings; }
        }
  [...]
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(MyCustomSettings))]
public class MyCustomSettings 
{
  private string cssClass = "default";
  public string CssClass
  {
    get { return cssClass; }
    set { cssClass = value; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just have that CssClass property in MyCustomGrid? Then it would work and be assignable via CssClass attribute in the markup. I would just add the properties to MyCustomGrid one by one, don't put them in another class.

Comment: Revealing the whole theory of this would take much time, and the question wasn't this, but the thing that how Microsoft guys did that. And also I am curious.