# What is the meaning of the term "Custom Class"?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

Many questions here on SO ask about custom classes. I, on the other hand, have no idea what they're talking about. "Custom class" seems to mean the same thing that I mean when I say "class".

What did I miss, back in the '80s, that keeps me from understanding?

---

I know that it's possible to purchase a packaged system - for Accounting, ERP, or something like that. You can then customize it, or add "custom code" to make the package do things that are specific to your business.

But that doesn't describe the process used in writing a .NET program. In this case, the entire purpose of the .NET Framework is to allow us to write our own code. There is nothing useful out of the box.

Comment: A class that isn't out of the box (framework / library / etc)?

Comment: wait, this was a serious question?  He has more rep than most dieties.   http://stackoverflow.com/users/159179/budda for instance.  Not meant to be rude just poking some fun here and there :)

Comment: P.S. Did they even *have* classes back in the '80s? :P

Comment: @Aaronaught: My language of choice was Simula-_67_, the language that introduced the term "class". So, from about 1976 onwards, yes.

Comment: With regards to the update, where have you seen the phrase "custom class" used in the context of writing .NET classes from scratch (absent any pluggable framework)?  That does sound odd, do you have a link to a question somewhere?

Comment: @Aaronaught: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199519/how-to-add-custom-properties-to-a-custom-webcontrol for just one. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intitle%3A1+custom for many (but ignore the SharePoint questions).

Comment: Hah - yeah, the wording on some of those questions is silly.  I think most of those people seem to be using it to mean "class I wrote" as opposed to "class that somebody else wrote."

Comment: @Aaronaught: that's the whole point of my question. I'm wondering where these people are coming from that they think of their own code using the same terms I used to use "little piece of code added to a packaged application".

Comment: Well, in that case, I think you have your answer; universally, the term refers to a class used to extend a library; locally, it's being used as a redundant buzzword.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Classes that you write yourself versus classes that come with the framework

Comment: This is the part I never really understood. The Framework doesn't actually _do_ anything. Without "custom classes", nothing happens. So why even make the distinction?

Comment: Maybe "custom" is used in a context specific manner.  They are "custom" to the application you are building.  Or its just semantics.

Answer (score 5):

The term "custom code" is generally used to refer to code you can write to extend an existing library or framework.  I suppose a "custom class" would be a class that you can plug in to a library or framework, perhaps by implementing an interface or inheriting from an abstract base class.

I'd probably call it a "customization class" instead, but it's certainly not the first awkwardly-named computing concept I've heard of here.

Comment: Yes, I think the important point is that it tends to mean that the class is focused on adding implementation (not interface) to a body of code that it is not a part of. For instance in Swing a custom `TableModel` would implement `TableModel` but, unlike `DefaultTableModel` not be part of Swing or the JDK.

Answer (score 5):

*Working with Custom Classes in dBASE*, Ken Mayer, Senior SQA Engineer, January 30, 2001 at http://www.dbase.com/knowledgebase/int/custom_classes/custclas.htm

> **What is a Class, and What is a Custom Class?**
>
> A Class is a definition of an object
>   -- it stores within its definition all of the properties,events and methods
>   associated with the object (this is,
>   by the way, 'encapsulation').
>
> A Custom Class is a developer defined
>   class, based on one of the stock
>   classes (classes built-in to dBASE). A
>   really good example of a Custom Class
>   file ships with dB2K -- it is in the
>   CLASSES (in Visual dBASE 7.x this is
>   the CUSTOM folder) directory, and is
>   called DATABUTTONS.CC. We will briefly
>   look at one of the buttons defined in
>   this class file, but most of the code
>   we will look at will be a bit
>   different than what's defined here.

---

Microsoft uses the term "custom" in its documentation for any extension of its supplied libraries.

If you wanted to extend a `ListBox` you would create a "custom control". If you wanted to extend a `Timer`, you would create a "custom component". Extend the `DataTable`, create a "custom class". They have done this for a long time. The earliest reference I can remember is the Visual Basic 5.0 manuals, which I think was 1996/1997.

There were "Custom App Wizard" projects, "Custom Business Objects in RDS [ADO]", "Custom Click Events", "Custom Properties in SQL Server MDX", "Custom OCX Controls", "Custom Controls with DHTML", and the list goes on and on. I estimate that the MSDN Library of October 2001 has over 300 index entries starting with the word "custom".

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that makes sense to me is either extending an existing class in a framework or library or something, or simply writing a class in an otherwise boilerplate code solution??

Excellent question!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is similar to **custom code**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to make a joke but instead I will put in a serious two cents;  People are used to making customizations -- when it comes to programing they must want a custom class.